# Using jQuery slideToggle when javascript is enabled instead of css display:block

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want a `div` with checkboxes to be displayed when mouse is hovered over button. I want `jQuery` code to be executed if `javascript` is enabled in browser. I have written `CSS` code for `hover` as work around if `javascript` is disabled. But `CSS` code always overrides `jQuery` code. How to achieve what I want.

The `html` code is as follows

```
<div id="button_div">
    <button id="hover_button" type="button">Select Options</button>
    <div id="checkbox_div">
        <form>
            <input id="one" type="checkbox" value="one" />
            <label for="one">One</label>
            <br />
            <input id="two" type="checkbox" value="two" />
            <label for="two">Two</label>
            <br />
            <input id="three" type="checkbox" value="three" />
            <label for="three">Three</label>
            <br />
            <input id="four" type="checkbox" value="four" />
            <label for="four">Four</label>
            <br />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

`CSS` is

```
#button_div {
    width: 120px;
}
#hover_button {
    width: 120px;
}
#checkbox_div {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top: -26px;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    width: 200px;
}
#button_div:hover>#checkbox_div {
    display: block;
}
```

`jQuery` code is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button_div").hover(function () {
        $("#checkbox_div").slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

This is the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/LdzPE/

Comment: You would have to look into A `.no-js` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to add a class to your button_div element, say `jscheck`. Then in your CSS, change the rule to target that new class.

So change `#button_div:hover>#checkbox_div` to `#button_div.jscheck:hover>#checkbox_div`.

Finally, in your jQuery, remove the class. That way, if JavaScript is enabled, the class gets removed and the CSS won't be applied. However if JavaScript isn't available, the class remains and the CSS works.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LdzPE/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

What others have said is correct.

Essentially you need to bind a class to the element that has the hover effects applied to it, e.g. `no-js`, and remove it when JavaScript is loaded, if it does.

Simple changes really.

#### HTML

```
<div id="button_div" class="no-js">
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $btnDiv = $("#button_div");

    $btnDiv.removeClass('no-js');
    $btnDiv.not('.no-js').hover(function () {
        $("#checkbox_div").slideDown("fast");
    });
});
```

#### CSS

```
#button_div.no-js:hover>#checkbox_div {
    display: block;
}
```

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9chct/).